# xsd element name by type

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a hierarchy of complex types.

For example: 
Abstract type Address with elements StreetNumber, StreetName and PostalCode
Concrete type HomeAddress with base Address
Concrete type BusinessAddress with base Address

The types HomeAddress and BusinessAddress don't have any additional elements and only the type is different.

Is it possible to have more than 1 address types in my XML?

```
<HomeAddress>
...
</HomeAddress>

<HomeAddress>
...
</HomeAddress>
```

In the xsd:

```
<xs:element name="address" type="Address" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

I want the element name to be dynamic based on the actual type.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "abstract" attribute and the xs:extension element:

```
<xs:complexType name="address" abstract="true">
  ...
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="homeAddress">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="mynamespace:address"></xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Like java, can a sub-type be assigned to super-type? How do i know what is the actual type?

Comment: Yes.  Try running your XSD through a serialization code generation tool like jaxb (for Java) or xsd.exe (for C#) to see how OO inheritance concepts map 1:1 into XML types.  Regarding the "actual type", a homeAddress is an address, so it's both.  Add another complex subtype (e.g. "businessAddress") to the example above if that helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020313/polymorphism-in-xsd-schema-and-jaxb-classes